# JSON emoji list shorcuts

Tags: emoji

I'm looking for a JSON list that associate shortcuts to native emoji

example:

```
{ ":)": "", ":p": "", ... }
```

Anyone know where to find it ?

Answer (score 0):

This could help you. Just that you have to prepare the list yourself - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons

Comment: That's great. May be you can publish the list you have prepared, so that someone else can use it.